# Adding a text to LaTeX that it shouldn't read

Tags: formatting

Hi guys I have to put a tiny code in my appendix for a dissertation that I am doing which looks like this

```
--
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Office Simulation File (DATA) Data Section Version 2014.1 Jun 25 2014
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- File: AUK_E100.DATA
-- Created on: 31-Jul-2015 at: 16:55:37
--
-- *****************************************************************************
-- *                                  WARNING                                  *
-- *                THIS FILE HAS BEEN AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED.                *
-- *          ANY ATTEMPT TO EDIT MANUALLY MAY RESULT IN INVALID DATA.         *
-- *****************************************************************************
--

--
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
RUNSPEC
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

TITLE
Auk Field

START
 1 'JAN' 2015 /

METRIC

OIL

WATER

NSTACK
 50 /

MONITOR

RSSPEC

NOINSPEC

MSGFILE
 1 /

DISPDIMS
 1 2 1 /

DIMENS
 50 50 25 /

EQLDIMS
 1 100 100 1 20 /

REGDIMS
 1 1 0 0 /

TABDIMS
 1 1 20 20 1 20 20 1 /

WELLDIMS
 6 17 3 6 /
```

This is just a tiny part of it but I want to add a complete code. However, it gives me really huge errors when I try to build the pdf, probably because there is something in there that is mixing itself with LaTeX coding. Is there a way to just paste the whole coding and tell LaTeX not to consider what every comes after this line or something? It would take me hours to read every line of code and see if LaTeX is mixing up something. Sorry if it's a really noob question, I am new to LaTeX.

Comment: Use package `listings` or `minted` or `fancyvrb` or ... to deal with stuff like that.

Comment: Or create it as a separate document and use \pdgpages or \includegraphcs

Comment: can u guys provide details on how to do that i have made a new document and put it in there and i am using the \input command... doesnt help..

Comment: What format is the new document in?  PDF is easy.

Comment: If it is straight text, start with \begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim} before getting fancy.

Comment: If you want input an external file, you can use `\verbatiminput` from the `verbatim` package.

Comment: can i past it in MS Word save it as pdf and add it below the heading with the \pdfpages?

Comment: See the [LaTeX wikibook about verbatim formatting](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Verbatim_text) for a simple fix.

Comment: Also `listings` package provides a `\lstinputlisting` command, allowing input external file verbatim.

Comment: @Bakhtawar Khattak, yes, except pdfpages is a package and \includepdf[pages=1,2]{filenamei} is the command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `verbatim` package, which provides `\verbatiminput`, or `listings` package (with `\lstinputlisting`). I use the latter because it allows lines breaking. The `\lstdefineformat` put a penalty after each `*` o `-`, allowing line breaks if there are a lot of `*` or `-`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file}
--

-- Office Simulation File (DATA) Data Section Version 2014.1 Jun 25 2014

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- File: AUK_E100.DATA

-- Created on: 31-Jul-2015 at: 16:55:37

-- ***************************************************************************** -- * WARNING * -- * THIS FILE HAS BEEN AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED. * -- * ANY ATTEMPT TO EDIT MANUALLY MAY RESULT IN INVALID DATA. *

-- *****************************************************************************

--

RUNSPEC

TITLE Auk Field

START 1 'JAN' 2015 /

METRIC

OIL

WATER

NSTACK 50 /

MONITOR

RSSPEC

NOINSPEC

MSGFILE 1 /

DISPDIMS 1 2 1 /

DIMENS 50 50 25 /

EQLDIMS 1 100 100 1 20 /

REGDIMS 1 1 0 0 /

TABDIMS 1 1 20 20 1 20 20 1 /

WELLDIMS 6 17 3 6 /
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[formats]{listings}
\makeatletter
\lstdefineformat{ast}{%
*=\string\penalty\@highpenalty,%
-=\string\penalty\@highpenalty,%
}
\makeatother

\lstset{%
breaklines=true,
format=ast
}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{file}
\end{document}
```